# Create new numeric columns from 1 string column

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, comparison

I'm a beginner. I have a dataset taken from [here](http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing) which consists of people profiles with different attributes, while `profession` is of them. There are 12 professions: admin., blue-collar, entrepreneur, housemaid, management, retired, self-employed, services, student, technician, unemployed, unknown.

I'd like to apply K-NN to that dataset, so I'd like to distribute the profession column into 12 new columns, and attribute `1` to the corresponding profession, and `0` to all the other 11 professions that don't belong to that person.

I tried `foreach package` and `for loops`, unsuccessfully. I'm not being able to work with `foreach`, and I don't know what to do next, from the following code:

```
jobs <- data[,2]
jobs
for (job in jobs) {
    print(job)
    #No idea how to create the new columns here, based on if conditionals
}
```

How would be the best way to do this?

Thanks.

---

Comment: Can you add a reproducible sample of the data (that can be accessed directly from your question and not the link)?

Comment: Not exactly what you are trying to do but look into the `factor` function in R

Comment: @BryanGoggin what do you mean with sample of data? Copy and paste the .csv here?

Comment: @user2864849 that didn't help much, but JTT already nailed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly solve the problem using a for loop, but may I suggest a solution that is more efficient in the long run: reshape2 package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/).

I have the data from bank-full.csv read into R in object bank. Next reshape2 package needs to be downloaded, installed, and loaded:

```
install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)
```

The data can then be shaped into a format where observations are on rows and jobs on columns. An accessory `id` column is first added to the data:

```
bank$id<-1:nrow(bank)
```

Then, taking the columns 2 and 18 (job and id) from the data frame `bank` and casting them into the aforementioned form can be done as:

```
tmp<-dcast(bank[,c(2, 18)], id~job, length)
```

That should give a new data frame `tmp`, where each job has it's own column. Since every id is present in the data only once, the `length` function used in the `dcast` function to aggregate the data puts just zeros and ones in every column.

Last, these new columns can be added to the original data set:

```
bank<-cbind(bank[,-18], tmp[,-1])
```

Negative subscripts inside the square brackets delete the columns from the dataset, so this simultaneously let's you get rid off the `id` column.

---

Another, even more efficient way to do this is to use the function `model.matrix`:

```
bank2<-cbind(bank, model.matrix( ~ 0 + job, bank))
```

This should give you a data frame with each job as a new column. Note however that it changes the column names a bit (adds job to the beginning of the job columns).

Comment: Thanks, both ways worked, indeed! Now I just have to delete the jobs column and change other columns string values to numeric ones. (-1, 0, 1, etc).
But on the code above, the last and most efficient one, I didn't understand the syntax of it. Could you explain, please? What does cbind do exactly, and what is model.matrix and its arguments?

Comment: The function `model.matrix` turns an R factor ("categorical variable") into a model matrix that can be used in a linear model (regression). It takes as an argument a formula that species how the model matrix is to be constructed. The formula in the example removes the intercept term from the matrix (term 0, a column filled with ones), and then recodes the levels of the job factor into individual columns. You might want to read R help on `?model.matrix`and `?formula`. Function cbind creates a new object by combining the columns of the two objects together.

Comment: You can test what `model.matrix` does just by running, e.g., `head(model.matrix( ~ 0 + job, bank))`. That gives you a few first rows from the resulting object.

Comment: When combining two different objects (data frames, matrices) in R using `cbind`, they need to have the same number of rows. Otherwise the combination fails.

Comment: That definitely cleared up many doubts, thank you! The last tip was really important hehe. Sorry that I can't upvote your answer (no reputation), but I accepted it. :) Thanks once again.